# Converting fat arrow function to a normal function

Tags: javascript

I am curious to know why this

```
let updateCatInfo = e.sender.dataSource._data.find(x => x.CatalogID == catID );
```

can't be converted to this

```
let updateCatInfo = e.sender.dataSource._data.find(function (x) { x.CatalogID == catID });
```

The reason why I am asking is because I am using .NET Web Browser Control and for some reason its not liking the fat arrow function (as seen in the first snippet) and tried to convert it to the second snippet. But the second snippet doesn't work.

So I am left to do this

```
for (let i = 0; i < e.sender.dataSource._data.length; i++) {
    if (e.sender.dataSource._data[i].CatalogID == catID) {
        updateCatInfo = e.sender.dataSource._data[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

for all the find functions that use a fat arrow function

Comment: @NinaScholz, the find works when i am not using the web browser control

Comment: Because you're missing a `return` statement in your second function. It's implicit in the arrow function. So, it's a typo, rather than inequality.

Comment: there are ways to convert it such as Babel or TS https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20updateCatInfo%20%3D%20e.sender.dataSource._data.find(x%20%3D%3E%20x.CatalogID%20%3D%3D%20catID%20)%3B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs regarding [Arrow Functions > Function bod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)y:

> #### Function body
>
> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.

The arrow function in your example has the concise body format, so there's an implicit return of the expression (`x.CatalogID == catID`).

When you use a function expression (or a block body arrow function), you have to explicitly declare the return:

```
let updateCatInfo = e.sender.dataSource._data.find(function (x) { return x.CatalogID == catID });
```

Comment: Will accept as answer once I am able, and thanks for the explaination